# How can I change my list in the controller class according to my choice?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a quiz page that lists the questions on my list. What I want to happen is that it calls up the relevant list according to the selection I made on the home page. For example I have two subjects. math and physics. There are two buttons on the home page. math and physics. whichever is selected, I want that topic to go to the quiz page.

It might be easy, but I couldn't. Because the place where my list was compiled is in the controller class. Not QuizPage class.

```
List<Question> _questions = EXAMPLE_LIST
      .map(
        (e) => Question(
            id: e["id"],
            question: e["question"],
            options: e["options"],
            answer: e["answer_index"]),
      )
      .toList();

  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;
```

I've tried: I made the `QuizPage()` wait for a String, send these values ​​with the buttons on the `HomePage()`, check it with `if` on the `QuizPage()` and return a list accordingly.

```
List getRightList() {              //and I changed EXAMPLE_LIST with QuizPage().getRightList()
        if (subject == "a") {       
          return ListA;
        } else if (subject == "b") {
          return ListB;
        }
      }
```

finally i get this error:

```
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Question>(Closure: (dynamic) => Question)
```

What's wrong with this way? I am also open to other suggestions.

Full code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:get/get.dart'; // get: ^3.25.4

//  Route         ================> 43. 62. line
//  QuizPage()     ===============> 79. line
//  QuestionController()  ========> 300. line

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.blue),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _questionController = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _questionController.resetQuestionNumber();
                _questionController.resetNumOfCorrectAns();
                _questionController._isAnswered = false;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => QuizPage(subject: "a")));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text(
                  "Go Quiz Page -subject a",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _questionController.resetQuestionNumber();
                _questionController.resetNumOfCorrectAns();
                _questionController._isAnswered = false;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => QuizPage(subject: "b")));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  "Go Quiz Page -subject b",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String subject;

  QuizPage({this.subject});

  static const List ListA = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Question 1 subject a",
      "options": ['option A  ', 'B', 'C ', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Question 2 subject a",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
  ];

  static const List ListB = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Q1 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C 2', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Q2 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "Q3 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B'],
      "answer_index": 0,
    },
  ];

  List getRightList() {
    if (subject == "a") {
      return ListA;
    } else if (subject == "b") {
      return ListB;
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _questionController = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Quiz Page"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Obx(
                    () => Center(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text:
                                "Question ${_questionController._questionNumber.value}",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 33, color: Colors.white70),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      "/${_questionController._questions.length}",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(color: Colors.white70, thickness: 1),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _questionController._pageController,
                    onPageChanged: _questionController.updateTheQuestionNum,
                    itemCount: _questionController.questions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                      question: _questionController.questions[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuestionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question question;

  const QuestionCard({
    Key key,
    @required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _controller = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            question.question,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    question.options.length,
                    (index) => Option(
                        text: question.options[index],
                        index: index,
                        press: () => _controller.isAnswered == false
                            ? {_controller.checkAns(question, index)}
                            : {}),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Option extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback press;

  const Option({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.index,
    @required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<QuestionController>(
        init: QuestionController(),
        builder: (q) {
          Color getRightColor() {
            if (q.isAnswered) {
              if (index == q._correctAns) {
                return Colors.green;
              } else if (index == q.selectedAns &&
                  q.selectedAns != q.correctAns) {
                return Colors.red;
              }
            }
            return Colors.blue;
          }

          return InkWell(
            onTap: press,
            child: Container(
              //-- Option
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: getRightColor(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "${index + 1}. $text",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {
  PageController _pageController;

  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

  List<Question> _questions = EXAMPLE_LIST // ??
      .map(
        (e) => Question(
            id: e["id"],
            question: e["question"],
            options: e["options"],
            answer: e["answer_index"]),
      )
      .toList();

  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;

  bool _isAnswered = false;

  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  int _correctAns;

  int get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;

  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;

  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _pageController = PageController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void resetQuestionNumber() => _questionNumber.value = 1;

  void resetNumOfCorrectAns() => _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    update();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
      _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 180), curve: Curves.ease);
    } else {}
  }

  void updateTheQuestionNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
  }
}

class Question {
  final int id, answer;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;

  Question({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.question,
    @required this.options,
    @required this.answer,
  });
}

const List EXAMPLE_LIST = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Question 1",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "Question 2",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "question": "Question 3",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "question": "Question 4",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 0,
  },
];
```

Comment: Is your listA or ListB initiated? That error means you haven’t initialised the lists

Comment: @Stijn2210 I did not do anything else but make the lists. I don't know how I can initialize the lists. How can I do it?

Comment: `List<Question> listA = [enter content here];`

Comment: @FloydWatson We already define in the controller class that the structure of the list is <`Question`>

Delete the one in the control class and separately When I do what it says for ListA and ListB, I get an error in the question.lenght line in different class.

I have added all the code and line numbers. Ready to work with EXAMPLE_LIST. Can you indicate where and how to use your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your code and adapted it to work. Ive changed the `QuestionController` and ive tried to highlight where you can see that changed. It will use `ListA` and `ListB`

```
class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {

  QuestionController({this.subject = 'a'});

  String subject;

  PageController _pageController;

  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;

  bool _isAnswered = false;

  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  int _correctAns;

  int get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;

  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;

  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _pageController = PageController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void resetQuestionNumber() => _questionNumber.value = 1;

  void resetNumOfCorrectAns() => _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    update();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
      _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 180), curve: Curves.ease);
    } else {}
  }

  void updateTheQuestionNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Code changed

  List<Question> get _questions => getRightList()
      .map(
        (e) => Question(
            id: e["id"],
            question: e["question"],
            options: e["options"],
            answer: e["answer_index"]),
      )
      .toList();

  void setSubject(String subject){
    this.subject = subject;
  }

  static const List ListA = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Question 1 subject a",
      "options": ['option A  ', 'B', 'C ', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Question 2 subject a",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
  ];

  static const List ListB = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Q1 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C 2', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Q2 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "Q3 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B'],
      "answer_index": 0,
    },
  ];

  List getRightList() {
    if (subject == "a") {
      return ListA;
    } else if (subject == "b") {
      return ListB;
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------

}
```

The biggest change was changing your reference to `_questions` to a `get` and accounting for `Null` or no selected list. However, there would need to be more steps made to make this solution robust.
`Null` has been slightly accounted for by giving the `subject` a default value of `'a'` as seen here: `QuestionController({this.subject = 'a'});`
But this is not robust and could still be broken

I also had to adapt your `InkWell` to set `subject`. please see below

Full working code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:get/get.dart'; // get: ^3.25.4

//  Route         ================> 43. 62. line
//  QuizPage()     ===============> 79. line
//  QuestionController()  ========> 300. line

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.blue),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _questionController = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _questionController.setSubject('a'); // Set subject
                _questionController.resetQuestionNumber();
                _questionController.resetNumOfCorrectAns();
                _questionController._isAnswered = false;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => QuizPage(subject: "a")));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Text(
                  "Go Quiz Page -subject a",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                _questionController.setSubject('b'); // Set subject
                _questionController.resetQuestionNumber();
                _questionController.resetNumOfCorrectAns();
                _questionController._isAnswered = false;
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => QuizPage(subject: "b")));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(22),
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  "Go Quiz Page -subject b",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String subject;

  QuizPage({this.subject});

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _questionController = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Quiz Page"),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                  child: Obx(
                    () => Center(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                            text:
                                "Question ${_questionController._questionNumber.value}",
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 33, color: Colors.white70),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      "/${_questionController._questions.length}",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25))
                            ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(color: Colors.white70, thickness: 1),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _questionController._pageController,
                    onPageChanged: _questionController.updateTheQuestionNum,
                    itemCount: _questionController.questions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => QuestionCard(
                      question: _questionController.questions[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuestionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question question;

  const QuestionCard({
    Key key,
    @required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _controller = Get.put(QuestionController());

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            question.question,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    question.options.length,
                    (index) => Option(
                        text: question.options[index],
                        index: index,
                        press: () => _controller.isAnswered == false
                            ? {_controller.checkAns(question, index)}
                            : {}),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Option extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback press;

  const Option({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.index,
    @required this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<QuestionController>(
        init: QuestionController(),
        builder: (q) {
          Color getRightColor() {
            if (q.isAnswered) {
              if (index == q._correctAns) {
                return Colors.green;
              } else if (index == q.selectedAns &&
                  q.selectedAns != q.correctAns) {
                return Colors.red;
              }
            }
            return Colors.blue;
          }

          return InkWell(
            onTap: press,
            child: Container(
              //-- Option
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: getRightColor(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "${index + 1}. $text",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class QuestionController extends GetxController
    with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {

  QuestionController({this.subject = 'a'});

  String subject;

  PageController _pageController;

  PageController get pageController => this._pageController;

  List<Question> get questions => this._questions;

  bool _isAnswered = false;

  bool get isAnswered => this._isAnswered;

  int _correctAns;

  int get correctAns => this._correctAns;

  int _selectedAns;

  int get selectedAns => this._selectedAns;

  RxInt _questionNumber = 1.obs;

  RxInt get questionNumber => this._questionNumber;

  int _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  int get numOfCorrectAns => this._numOfCorrectAns;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    _pageController = PageController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void resetQuestionNumber() => _questionNumber.value = 1;

  void resetNumOfCorrectAns() => _numOfCorrectAns = 0;

  void checkAns(Question question, int selectedIndex) {
    _isAnswered = true;
    _correctAns = question.answer;
    _selectedAns = selectedIndex;

    if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) _numOfCorrectAns++;

    update();

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      nextQuestion();
    });
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber.value != _questions.length) {
      _isAnswered = false;
      _pageController.nextPage(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 180), curve: Curves.ease);
    } else {}
  }

  void updateTheQuestionNum(int index) {
    _questionNumber.value = index + 1;
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------
  // Code changed

  List<Question> get _questions => getRightList()
      .map(
        (e) => Question(
            id: e["id"],
            question: e["question"],
            options: e["options"],
            answer: e["answer_index"]),
      )
      .toList();

  void setSubject(String subject){
    this.subject = subject;
  }

  static const List ListA = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Question 1 subject a",
      "options": ['option A  ', 'B', 'C ', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Question 2 subject a",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
  ];

  static const List ListB = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "Q1 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C 2', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "Q2 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      "answer_index": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "Q3 subject b",
      "options": ['option A', 'B'],
      "answer_index": 0,
    },
  ];

  List getRightList() {
    if (subject == "a") {
      return ListA;
    } else if (subject == "b") {
      return ListB;
    }
    return null;
  }

  // ----------------------------------------------------------

}

class Question {
  final int id, answer;
  final String question;
  final List<String> options;

  Question({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.question,
    @required this.options,
    @required this.answer,
  });
}

const List EXAMPLE_LIST = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "question": "Question 1",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "question": "Question 2",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 2,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "question": "Question 3",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "question": "Question 4",
    "options": ['option A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    "answer_index": 0,
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been dealing with this for two days. If things are going smoother with the `Provider` package, you can be sure that I will take care of it. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the rest of it. Hope it goes smoothly